# Corda 4 - How to convert a CordaX500Name Party object to string

Tags: corda

I need to get the string value of the CordaX500Name party name. I want to save it as string datatype in the database

Following is the code that retrieves the party name of the current node -

```
private val myLegalName = services.proxy.nodeInfo().legalIdentities.first().name
val thisParty = services.proxy.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(myLegalName);
```

How to convert "thisParty" to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line of code (without the `.name`) already returns `thisParty`!
You are doing the following circle:
 1. `services.proxy.nodeInfo().legalIdentities.first()` returns type `Party` (i.e. `thisParty`).
 2. When you added `.name` it returns `CordaX500Name` of that party.
 3. Then you used `services.proxy.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name` on that X500 name to return the party which you already had in the first line `services.proxy.nodeInfo().legalIdentities.first()`

Not sure what you're trying to do, but to get the `.toString()` of a party, I assume you meant to return something like `O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB`. To do that: `thisParty.name.toString()`